# How to remove value while getting letter with number using php

Tags: php, arrays

i need one help.i need to remove those ids which has also some letters and inserted rest into a array using PHP. i am explaining my code below.

```
http://oditek.in/spesh/mobileapi/categoryproduct.php?item=1&acn=5&subcat_id=a15,15,16
```

here in `subcat_id` i have one id `a15`i need to remove this type of ids wheile comes and rest should insert into a array.Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to take the string `a15,15,16`, convert to an array, and remove the non-numeric values?

If so, it's pretty simple:

```
$subcatArray = explode(',', $_GET['subcat_id']);
$subcatArrayNumeric = array_filter($subcat, 'is_numeric');
```

Now `$subcatArrayNumeric` will be an array with '15' and '16' in it, only.

Working example: https://3v4l.org/hWSOj

Answer (score 0):

Try [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) for getting numeric ids

```
$subcatid = explode(",",$_GET['subcat_id']);
$arrId = [];
foreach($subcatid AS $id) {
    $arrId[] = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $id);
}
var_dump($arrId);  //$arrId contains all the numeric IDs only
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are not getting the URL from the request you would have to parse it first.

```
<?php

$url = "http://oditek.in/spesh/mobileapi/categoryproduct.php?item=1&acn=5&subcat_id=a15,15,16";
$query_str = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
parse_str($query_str, $query_params);
$ids = explode(",",$query_params['subcat_id']);
print_r($ids);
foreach( $ids as $index => $id){
    if( is_numeric($id) === false ){
        unset($ids[$index]);
    }
}
print_r($ids);
?>
```

The for loop in my example could be replaced by  array_filter($ids, 'is_numeric') like in jszobody answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$url = 'http://oditek.in/spesh/mobileapi/categoryproduct.php?item=1&acn=5&subcat_id=a15,15,16';

$parts = parse_url($url);
$q = array();
parse_str($parts['query'], $q);

$subcatIds = explode(',', $q['subcat_id']);
$subcatIds = array_map(function($element){ return filter_var($element, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);}, $subcatIds);

print_r($subcatIds);
```

Result is:

```
Array ( [0] => 15 [1] => 15 [2] => 16 )
```

Working example: [CLICK!](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/edf140a09e407d65a067a7c80d2fbbc90dd26689)

So basically, if you have `subcat_id` in `$_GET`, then you need only two lines:

```
$subcatIds = explode(',', $_GET['subcat_id']);
$subcatIds = array_map(function($element){ return filter_var($element, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);}, $subcatIds);
```